# Perform multiline search

Tags: python-3.x

My current script is working (see below) but matches on single lines.  How can I match multiple lines?

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        check1 = "fail"
        check2 = "fail"
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("logging buffered 16384"):
                check1 = 'pass'
            if line.startswith("logging console informational"):
                check2 = 'pass'
        fh.write("{},{},{}\n".format(filename, check1, check2))
fh.close()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "match multiple lines" ?

Comment: I would like to create a single match for 2 or more lines.  Let's say I have one line that says "this is line1" and line 2 says "this is line2".  I want the script to search the file for those 2 lines and return "pass" or "fail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `result` will have the value True if all the items in `checks` is present in the `file`

```
checks = ["line1", "line2"]
file = ["line3", "line4", line5", "line1", "line2"]
result = (all([True for line in checks if line in file]))
```

Define the lines you want to search through as a list, and run the above code on your file.